# Python mysql connector: Can't connect from laptop to a remote DB, but can successfully from another laptop

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-rds, mysql-python

On Py3.7, I'm running:

```
>>> from mysql import connector as sql
>>> db_connection = sql.connect(host='blablasmth.rds.amazonaws.com', database='mydbname', user='me', password='abcd1234')
```

The DB requires an openVPN connection, so 1st I connect to the VPN, then run these lines.

Now, on my laptop (Py3.7.3), I connect successfully.
On my other laptop (Py3.7.1), with the same lines exactly (^C-^V), I get either

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond ... timeout ... 10060
```

or (after installing `pip install mysql-connector-python` with some desparate hope)

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blablasmth.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)
```

I've tried it a number of times over a few days, and this behaviour is consistent. My VPN connection looks fine in both machines (OpenVPN symbol is green).

I've also tried to disable the firewall on my failing machine, with no different result.

Last, I've installed mysql-workbench. Again, can't connect. Switching machine, connect successfully.

Any Ideas? please...